# Concavity related question.

Tags: calculus

From a graph of $f'(x)$, how to find on what intervals $f(x)$ is increasing or decreasing, $f'(x)$ is increasing or decreasing, on what intervals $f(x)$ is concave up or down, $f'(x)$ is concave up or down?

This is the graph of $f'(x)$

[image: This is the graph of $f'(x)$]

So far, what I've tried:

for $f(x):$ Increasing on $(-5, -3.25)\cup (-1.5, 1)$ and Decreasing on $(-3.25, -1.5) \cup (1,6)$
for $f'(x):$ Increasing on $(-2.5, 0) \cup (3.5, 6)$ and Decreasing on $(-5, -2.5) \cup (0, 3.5)$

Comment: Concavities are separated by the inflection points, at $-1.5$ and $2$.

Comment: Your answers are quite correct.

Comment: Oh, then of course (I thought that was $f$), comment deleted.

Comment: @Yves: Yes, I need the intervals of concavity for f and f'.

Comment: For $f$ use the roots of the derivative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concave up is where the graph looks like a smile, and concave down is where the graph looks like a frown. It looks like the graph is frowning in the interval $(-1.5,2)$, so concave down there, and smiling in $(-4.5,-1.5)$ and in $(2,5.5)$, so concave up there. When you took a picture, your book was not flat, and this distorted the graph a bit, so you take a look one more time in your book :)